# Python `YYYY-MM-DD`

Tags: python, calendar, gtk, pygtk, rfc3339

In Python, what is the best way to get the
**RFC 3339 `YYYY-MM-DD`** text from the output of `gtk.Calendar::get_date()`?

Comment: if the answer does fit, you must accept!

Comment: @The Elite Gentleman, Manoj Govindan: This is the first time one of my questions has been answered to my satisfaction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to Mark and treeface for the solutions, but it seems I've invented a better one:

```
year, month, day = cal.get_date()
return '{0:04d}-{1:02d}-{2:02d}'.format(year, month+1, day)
```

This solution is shorter, easier to understand (in my opinion), and I believe takes less processing as it cuts out the stage where the tuple is converted into UNIX time.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [docs](http://www.pygtk.org/docs/pygtk/class-gtkcalendar.html#method-gtkcalendar--get-date), the get_date returns a tuple of (year,month,day), where month 0 to 11 and day is 1 to 31, so:

```
import datetime
dtTuple = calControl.get_date()
dtObj = datetime.datetime(dtTuple[0], dtTuple[1] + 1, dtTuple[2]) #add one to month to make it 1 to 12
print dtObj.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be useful to you:

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/time_strftime.htm

I've also just looked around for this gtk get_date method and I was able to find some code that handles it like this:

```
//here replace "self.window.get_date()" with "gtk.Calendar::get_date()"
year, month, day = self.window.get_date()
mytime = time.mktime((year, month+1, day, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0))
return time.strftime("%x", time.gmtime(mytime))
```

So just replace "%x" with "%G-%m-%d" and I think it would work. Or at least it's worth a try.